# How to clear values of a instance of a type struct dynamically

Tags: struct, go

Is it possible with Go to make a method that dynamically clears the values of a instance of a struct?

```
type A struct {
    Name string
    Level int
}

type B struct {
    Skill string
}

func main() {
    a := A{"Momo", 1}
    b := B{"Starfall"}

    // outputs
    // {"Momo", 1}
    // {"Starfall"}

    clear(a)
    clear(b)

    // outputs
    // { , 0}
    // { }
}

func clear(v interface{}) {
    // some code
}
```

Comment: As you're not passing a pointer, your function which returns nothing can't clear a because it doesn't know a, only a copy of the value.

Comment: Just assign a zero value like this `a=A{}` which is much simpler and more readable.

Comment: technically an interface value *is* a reference type. So the clear function as he wrote it could clear a struct. However he would have to use a lot of reflection. Much easier to just use a zero value as others have said.

Comment: @JeremyWall: that's incorrect. You cannot get a reference to the original value through an interface, even via reflection.

Comment: @JimB I don't understand.  The clear example in your own answer modifies the original value through an interface via reflection.

Comment: @zmb, it's because my answer is using a pointer. It has nothing to do with an interface being a "reference type" (which is a bit of a misnomer), it's just extracting a pointer from an interface. The original question is *not* passing a pointer, and because everything in Go is a value, and all assignments are a copy, there is no way to modify the values of a and b in that manner.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't modify the original values without passing a pointer to them.

It's much easier and more clear to simply assign a new zero value in your code. If your types are more complex, you can replace the values with a constructor, or provide `Reset()` methods for your types with a pointer receiver.

If you really want to see how to do it via reflection your `clear` function could look like: http://play.golang.org/p/g0zIzQA06b

```
func clear(v interface{}) {
    p := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem()
    p.Set(reflect.Zero(p.Type()))
}
```

(This will panic if you pass in a non-pointer value)

Comment: FYI, instead of a `Clear()` method there is precedent in the standard library of using `Reset()`. E.g. [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Reset), [`hash.Hash`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash), etc.

Comment: Seems clear function doesn't work for string type: "reflect: call of reflect.Value.Elem on string Value"

Comment: the answer from @AESTHETICS is more correct, as this solution does in-fact fail.
myStructVar = myBaseStruct{}
This works, would be nice to have a struct method called reset.

Comment: @Cyberience: yes, AESTHETICS answer would be preferred if the real use code was as simple as the example provided. While that should be the preferred method for most code, it makes no attempt to answer the question posted; especially since the OP may actually have a use case for replacing various arbitrary values with their zero value equivalent (which is not entirely unheard of)

Answer (score 7):

Even though this question was first asked 3 years and 9 months ago it IMO still does not have a good answer so let me propose one.

There is no need for reflection, or to create a new instance each time you want to clear your variable. Instead create one pristine new instance that you leave in its initial zeroed state which you can then copy over your object's memory when you want to `Reset()` it. *(Hat tip to @DaveC for pointing out that a `Reset()` method is more idiomatic.)*

You simply copy from your zeroed value to the location at which your object points to using pointers. The following reads *"Copy the **value** of the memory that `zeroA` references to the **memory location** that `a` references.":*

```
*a = *zeroA
```

Here is my full example which you can also try in [the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HJax8mDJT4W). *(Note that since your [receiver](https://tour.golang.org/methods/4) for `Reset()` is a pointer to type `A` then calling the `Reset()` method allows you to update the value of `a` where the update survives past the end of the method call):*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    Name string
    Level int
}
var zeroA = &A{}
func (a *A) Reset() {
    *a = *zeroA
}

func main() {
    a1 := A{"Momo", 1}
    a2 := &a1
    a3 := a1

    fmt.Println(a1)
    fmt.Println(a2)
    fmt.Println(a3)

    a1.Reset()

    fmt.Println(a1)
    fmt.Println(a2)
    fmt.Println(a3)
}
```

And here is your output *(Note that I prove that your variable is zeroed out and a pointer to that variable is also zeroed, but if you made a *copy* of the original it is not zeroed):*

```
{Momo 1}
&{Momo 1}
{Momo 1}
{ 0}
&{ 0}
{Momo 1}
```

You can also use this technique to copy over the values of a struct that contains default values. *However* be aware that this is a **shallow copy**, not a deep copy. If your `struct` contains any properties that are pointers this approach  will copy the pointer values over too and will not allocate memory to point to new copies of the values pointed to. So you will need to do extra work in `Reset()` if you want to reset your struct to new defaults, including copies of any sub-structs that are declared with pointers.

I hope this helps others so they do not have to learn this the hard way like it took me.

Answer (score 6):

You can just set it to an empty struct like so:

```
var obj myStruct
obj.field1 = "apple"
obj.field2 = 12

// Reset struct.
obj = myStruct{}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/Rf1BqfFe3IQ

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to reassign the value with an empty object of the struct which will reset the values.

```
a := A{"Momo", 1}
b := B{"Starfall"}

fmt.Println(a)
fmt.Println(b)
// outputs
// {"Momo", 1}
// {"Starfall"}

a = A{}
b = B{}
// outputs
// { , 0}
// { }
```

https://play.golang.org/p/CJ6cx2TFytY

Comment: Is this recommended?

Comment: I have seen it done in multiple languages and it works. No reason not to use it. It’s just like reassigning the value of the object.

Comment: This approach does a new allocation, and if your goal is to reuse objects in order to minimize allocations in programs that create a lot of objects quickly and the throws them away this won't help.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel where did you get this idea? It’s not true. It’s still the same object with different value.

Comment: Let's be more precise than the term "object," and I'll just talk about `A` since the same will apply to `B`.

We have 1.) the **variable** `A`, 2.) the **memory** that stores `{"Momo", 1}` and and `{ , 0}`, and 3.) the **address** of the memory that stores  `{"Momo", 1}` and `{ , 0}`.

You are correct that it will still be _variable_ `A`, but incorrect in that the _address_ to the difference values in memory will be the same. When you call `A{}` it allocates new memory and assigns a that address to `A` while making the memory `{"Momo", 1}` available to the garbage collector.

Comment: You can see what I am referring to in this [Go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/IES0jjD2Qrb).

Comment: Nice Pepega, you did not applied my example but yours with pointers to an object. Check this https://play.golang.org/p/w_mrVKB2rMQ